# Much vs Many with rank

Tags: word-choice, modifiers

When We ask someone about their rank, what do we ask them?

> How many rank did you get in your exam?
>
> or
>
> How much rank did you get in your exam?

I know the above question can also be asked as "what rank did you get?", but which one from above is right.

Comment: Neither "how many rank" nor "how much rank" is used in AmE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In American English, you'd ask "what grade did you get on your exam?"

If you must use the word rank, you'd ask "what rank did you get on your exam?" This would mean, how did you place relative to the other people who took the exam.

"Rank" in this context is not countable (although you could ask "how many ranks are there for officers in the army?") so you can't ask about "how many rank". It is also not something whose quantity is measurable (you can't have "10 pounds of rank" or "3 bushels of rank") so you can't ask about "how much rank".

Comment: Also possible is "where did you rank on the exam?" (relative to other students. What score or what mark in more common than what grade in my (Aus) experience.

Comment: @Peter, yes, and we can even say "I fell 3 ranks" if on the previous exam I was ranked 10th and on the latest one I ranked 13th. But we'd use "rank" as a count noun only for comparisons between exams, not for the results of a single exam. In AmE we can ask about the "score" on an exam but we almost never use "mark" in this context.